# Dictionary returning only the Last Item in List Value

Tags: python, list, if-statement, string-formatting, dictionary-comprehension

I have 2 lists as inputs:

```
A = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
sessionid = [1, 1, 3, 2, 2]
```

I want to use **dictionary comprehension** without importing any libraries to generate the following output, with the key as 'Session x' by using string formatting:

```
{'Session 1': ['A','B'], 'Session 2': ['D','E'], 'Session 3': ['C']}
```

I tried with this code:

```
dictb = {'Session {}'.format(session): [a if session not in dictb.keys() else [a]] for a,session in list(zip(A,sessionid))}
```

but it returns me this:

```
{'Session 1': ['B'], 'Session 3': ['C'], 'Session 2': ['E']}
```

I think there is a problem with `if-else statement` in the comprehension. How should I improve this?

Comment: Do you want a better way, something short and pythonic?

Comment: I heard that `defaultdict`  can do the similar things

Comment: Yes but since you don't want to import anything, we can go without that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible solution:

```
dictb = {f'Session {k}': [v for v, i in zip(A, sessionid) if k == i]
         for k in sorted(set(sessionid))}
```

Output:

```
{'Session 1': ['A', 'B'], 'Session 2': ['D', 'E'], 'Session 3': ['C']}
```

Comment: What is the difference between `sorted(sessionid)` and `sorted(set(sessionid))`?

Comment: @cwyjm when you apply `set` to a list, it keeps the elements without the doubles. So in this case the first piece of code returns `[1,1,2,2,3]`, the second returns `[1,2,3]`

Comment: So `set` only returns the distinct values in the list. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're generating a dictionary with string keys that have the format `Session{}` and checking if the dictionary has integer keys, which it always doesn't and thus takes the part after `else`. When the same integer comes, it updates the value and that's why you're seeing the last updated value. I wouldn't recommend doing what you want using a dict comprehension, for both performance and readability reasons but if you really want to, try (Not tested):

```py
dictb = {'Session {}'.format(session): [dictb['Session {}'.format(session)] + [a] if 'Session {}'.format(session) not in dictb.keys() else [a]] for a,session in list(zip(A,sessionid))}
```

The recommended approach would be:

```py
dictb = {}
for a, session in zip(A, sessionid):
    key = 'Session {}'.format(session)
    if key in dictb:
        dictb[key].append(a)
    else:
        dictb[key] = [a]
```

Comment: I always find dictionary comprehension difficult because of its readability. It is true that your approach is easier to follow. The logic is clearer when using a for loop. But I am required to use comprehension in this task so.. Thank you for your answers anyway! :)